# how to Make Http request from reactjs ?

Tags: database, reactjs, zend-framework, httprequest, zend-framework3

I am using react js as front end  and zf3 as a backend in my ToDo application. I put all my React folder and files in public folder of Zend project. As of now, it is  just Simple app there is no database connection. Now I want to add Db for storing tasks. but as a newbie, I don't know how to make Http request for edit delete and add a task. please explain with a example. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: use `fetch` api reference : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). It allows you to set some default configuration so that you don't need to do it with every request:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "my-awesome-token";
axios.defaults.baseURL = http://www.somehost.com/api;
...
axios.get('/people')
    .then(response => handleResponse(response))
    .catch(error => handleError(error)) 
// actually shoots to http://www.somehost.com/api/people with Authorization header
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many npm modules for http request. Here is a smiple one: https://github.com/request/request

Answer (score 0):

```
install axios

$ npm install axios


import axios

import axios from 'axios';

get request

axios.get('api url').then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});


post request

var body = {
    firstName: 'testName',
    lastName: 'testLastName'
};

axios.post('api url',body).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```